# Can I discover the name of a caller procedure inside the called one?

Tags: mysql

When you have a procedure that is called by many others, can you discover inside the "called" procedure the name of the "caller procedure"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is no "call-stack" you can query. You have to pass the name of the caller in a parameter (or use an user-defined variable).